# Multiple targets in xcode cause differences in memory management

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I have multiple targets in xcode that seem to behave differently when it comes to memory management.

I have noticed that one of my targets does not release my UIViewControllers, while the other targets release them when I roughly expect them to. 
The screenshots below show the difference I see when watching a specific UIViewController using Instruments and executing the same flows.

Target 1:
[image]

Target 2: 
[image: Retained viewcontrollers]

My question is: which properties could be responsible for this difference in behaviour, or could there be another culprit at work that I am missing?

(As far as I investigated, I don't see any significant differences in targets, except for the *code signing* properties)

Comment: Debug versus Release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you disable NSZombie while investigating memory release problems. NSZombie will retain objects to be able to show the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks! I still had my NSZombieEnabled variable enabled indeed.